# Loop to assign variables to cut pieces of the filename then use in a command for each file in a dir

Tags: bash, loops, amazon-s3

I want to upload files into date partitioned s3 objects. I have a lot of files in the directory and want to move each file to the folder structure derived from the date in the filename.

```
for file in /home/ec2-user/clickparts/t*; do year="${file:9:4}"; month="${file:14:2}"; day="${file:17:2}"; aws s3 cp "$file" s3://bk-py-dev/json/clicks/clickpartition/$year/$month/$day/; done
```

It would be awesome if I could do it in this one-liner format. Filename is in format the_date=2019-03-05.json

Answer (score 0):

You already have a nice solution. An alternative would be

```
topdir="bk-py-dev/json/clicks/clickpartition"
while IFS=- read -r xxxyear month dayjson; do
   aws s3 cp "${xxxyear}-${month}-${dayjson}" s3://${topdir}/${xxxyear#*=}/${month}/${dayjson%.*}
done < <(find * -maxdepth 0 -type f -name '*.json' )
```

I don't know why you would like to have it in one line.
You could add a function with this code in your `.bashrc` like `upload2s3() {..}`, and now you can call the oneliner `upload2s3`.